# How to hide buttons based on your "job"?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating an app and I want that the buttons appear based on your `$job`. There are 4 jobs, which are all in mysql databases:

1. student
2. teacher
3. staff
4. principal,

The signup button can only be seen by teacher, staff and principal.

But I don't know how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
   session_start();

   include("connection.php");
   include("functions.php");

   $user_data = check_login($con);

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
       $job = $_POST['job'];
   }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> NetPlat </title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="login.php">
        <button id="button">Logout</button>
    </a><br><br>
    <a href="signup.php">
        <button>Signup Student</button>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you check what "job" someone has?  Just wrap the job-specific HTML content in a PHP `if` block.  For example: `<?php if($someCondition) { ?> <div>some content</div> <?php } ?>`

Comment: I presume $user_data might list the $job?  Remember - you can add `<?php ... ?>` sections *WITHIN* your HTML.  For example, `<?php if ($user.job == 'teacher') { ?> <a href="signup.php">...<?php } else {...}`

Comment: fyi, `<button>` inside `<a>` is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surrounding the button markup with a simple `if` statement using the `in_array` function to check that the job is allowed, will work.

```php
<?php
if(in_array($job, ['teacher', 'staff', 'principal']))
{
?>
    <a href="signup.php">
        <button>Signup Student</button>
    </a>
<?php
}
?>
```

The above will only output the button html if the value of `$job` is found in the array.

Comment: But it shows me an undefied variable